# Suppress Tags from HTML with AgilityHTMLPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need help because I am not really used to work with HTML. I show a webdocument from my code, the web document read an HTML file, containing some Images.
Everytime, just before the Image tag, I observed two tags who create some wrong caracters. An example would be better.

```
<p ><br clear=all> </span>
<img border=0 width=265 height=105 id="Picture 84856"
   src="Test_HTML/image272.jpg"></p>
```

the printing is partially correct because it  shows the Images and a lots of wrong ÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂ characters.
So I decided to try to cut the   tags.

I don't know how to do this. Perhaps I am completely wrong but I think it is good start, isn't it?
My test to suppress these tags in a Html node is

```
        public void ShowTag(string tag)
    {
       
         string innerHtml= "//div[@id='"+tag+ "']";
        string inner = "//p";
        string brToRemove = "//br";
        string spanToRemove = "//span";
        

        
        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(innerHtml);
        bool br_deleted = false;
        foreach (HtmlNode nd in nodes.SelectNodes(inner))
        {
          
            foreach (HtmlNode child in nd.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child.Name == "br")
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    a++;
                 
                    
                    child.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child);
                    br_deleted = true;
                }
                if(child.Name=="span")
                {
                    int b = 0;
                    b++;
                    if (br_deleted == true)
                    {
                      
                        //nd.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child);
                        child.Remove();
                        br_deleted = false;
                    }
                    
                }
                        
            }
                        
        }
```

but I cannot remove the child, do you have any idea?

Comment: You might be better off telling whoever created that piece of garbage that is HTML-like to write proper markup code. Fixing broken code after the fact is pointless.

Comment: You have right, but if for some reasons I cannot find another solution I have to find a way.

Comment: Well, an HTML parser can only do so much if what they have to parse is not valid HTML. You might have to go through it with RegEx to actually create valid HTML from it.

Comment: In the end, it's garbage-in, garbage-out. Again, it might be worth a try to just change the garbage-in part, because you cannot magically create gold from garbage, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Effectevely , you have right it is not normal but it comes from the conversion WORD to HTML. The main problem comes from the fact that children is into a loop and i cannot modify the collection.

Comment: Well, then I guess the solution would be to not do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I founded where the problem came from: When selecting the good node, I needed to add the Headers so i could identify the encoding.

```
            string innerHtml = "//div[@id='" + tag + "']";
            string inner = "//p";                              
            webbrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
            LoadDocument();
            HtmlNode nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(innerHtml);
            HtmlNode head = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");

            head.AppendChild(nodes);

            webbrowser.NavigateToString(head.InnerHtml);
```